# Short the circuit of a voltage controlled voltage source when finding out the v(t) for \$t>0\$

Tags: transient, source

**Question**

Find v(t) for t<0 and t>0 in the circuit below.

[image]

---

**Solution**

[image]

---

**My Question**

Why we can see the voltage controlled voltage source as a shorted circuit when finding the v(t) for \$t>0\$? [Circuit (b)]

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why we can see the voltage controlled voltage source as a shorted
>   circuit when finding the v(t) for t>0?

First of all, it's not a *voltage* controlled voltage source, it's a *current* controlled voltage source (CCVS) since the controlling variable is the *current* \$i_o\$.

Now, answer the following questions:

(1) What must be the value of \$i_0\$ when \$t > 0\$?

(2) Given the answer to the previous question, what is the voltage across the CCVS when \$t > 0\$?

(3) Given the answer to the previous question, what can we replace the CCVS with?

Comment: This was not intuitive to me because Io is defined as the current in that top branch. When the switch closes, that top branch is simply re-directed through the 8 Ohm resistor. The only way for the dependent source to be 0 would be if Io = 0, which is not the case, right? For Io = 0, the voltage at the top node would have to be 20V so no current flows through the 8 ohm resistor.

Comment: (1) When t>0, Io=0A. (2) 4Io=0V. (3) Since the voltage is equal to 0V, we can see it as a shorted circuit with no potential difference.

Answer (score 0):

Something to keep in mind as you analyze your circuits and you ask values of t<0. In DC, an inductor is seen as an open circuit at t=0, and after five time constants it is seen as a short circuit, while the opposite is true for a capacitor where it is seen as a short circuit at t=0, and an open circuit after five time constants. Never confuse voltage with current, even across a one ohm resistor where the voltage and the current is the same number, and this is what you have in your circuit question, but not as simple as with a one ohm resistor.